# Problem importing org.opensearch.knn in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

My question is about correctly using the Java API of opensearch to with with the KNN plugin and make KNN queries in Java. How can I add `org.opensearch.plugin:opensearch-knn` as a dependency to my Java project and use it?

I’ve added K-NN plugin as dependency in my build.gradle:

```
implementation("org.opensearch.plugin:opensearch-knn:2.3.0.0")
```

But I still get unresolved reference error when trying to import anything from `org.opensearch.knn`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.
The code in `org.opensearch.knn` such as the `kNNQuerybuilder` class are for internal use in the package. So that means I shouldn't take dependency in K-NN plugin and use the [Java client](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java).